# Converting a price string into an integer

Tags: java

I need to convert prices into integers, like such:

- (String) 12,000 to (int) 12000
- 245.00 to (int) 245

How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: Use the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

Comment: What if the price is `"245.67"`?  What should the result be?

Comment: if the price is 245.67 ,then result should be 246[converting the decimal value in to the integer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much shorter than the other solutions:

```
public static int parseStringToInt(String s){
        s = s.replaceAll(",", ""); //remove commas
        return (int)Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s)); //return rounded double cast to int
    }
```

Use it like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] m = {"12,000", "245.67"};
        for (String s : m){
            System.out.println(parseStringToInt(s));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The javadoc of String.replaceAll() would suggest it takes a regex, thus is a very expensive operation. In Java8, they added specific handling for single-character replacements, so widespread was the usage of this construct by devs not reading docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); // Use Locale?
int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
for(int  i = 0 ; i < strings.length ; ++i) {
    ints[i] = nf.parse(strings[i]).intValue();
}
```

Comment: hi jean,
  Thanks for the suggestion ,but the thing is i have an array which contain string of both combination[12,000 and 245.00] .i need to convert both into an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int convertDoubleToInt(double d){
    //rounds off to the nearest 100
    long l = Math.round(d);
    int i = (int) l;
    return i;
}

public static double convertCommaDoubleToInt(String s) throws ParseException{
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    Number number = nf.parse(s);
    return number.doubleValue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String[] moneys = {"12,000", "245.76"};

    for(String n: moneys){
        Double d = convertCommaDoubleToInt(n);//first remove the comma, if there
        System.out.println(convertDoubleToInt(d)); //then convert double into int
    }


}
```

Comment: it throwed the expections as below

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "  499.00"